# Microsoft login via Oauth2 returns status code 200 instead of 302

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, python-requests, odata

The Oauth2 authentication doesn't work when I follow the protocol programatically (python2 and requests). But it works properly when I use a browser. My purpose is to retrieve the authorisation code from the redirected url in order to generate an access token.

Should I add something in the header to allow the redirection ?

```
import requests
uri = https://login.microsoftonline.com/0000-0000-0000-0000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=codel&client_id=0000-0000-0000-0000-0000&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2F&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:80%2F
r = requests.get(uri)
print r.url
print r.status_code
print r.history
```

The status code is `200` but I am expecting a `302` status and a result url like this: `localhost:80/?code=mycode&state=mystate&session_state=thesessionstate`

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect a 302? That would require you to pass in the session cookie as well.

It's returning you a 200 OK because the response contains the login screen.

When you have a script like this, you should probably be using Client Credentials flow (which uses app permissions): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service.

Another option is Device Code flow, which I describe in my blog: https://joonasw.net/view/device-code-flow.

Comment: I want to automatise the authentication so I don't need the login screen but I need a payload response containing the code

Comment: When you say "automate", it means you need to do client credentials flow, or Resource Owner Password Credentials flow (which I would not recommend unless it's your only option). You can only get an authorisation code via a browser, no other options.

Comment: All the flows I mentioned give you access tokens, use the right one for your scenario.

Comment: Yes but what if the token expires ? should I generate a new device code every day according to the schedule time ?

Comment: With client credentials, you can get a new token whenever you want with the same flow. With ROPC, you get a refresh token, which you can use to get new tokens. The downside of refresh tokens is that they can be revoked. For example if the user who you got the token for changes their password, all refresh tokens for that user expire. It does not apply to client credentials since there is no refresh tokens, and there is no user involved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these headers:

```
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Comment: I've tried this trick, but apparently the browser generate cookies in the header